# Simple inventory

Tags: cognito-forms

I just need a simple way to calculate inventory. Say we have 100 items to sell, I need it to count down each time an order is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/) does not yet support inventory tracking and limits - however, this is a proposed feature on the public Idea Board:

https://trello.com/c/mxxJ71Vs/225-inventory-limits

Feel free to vote for this feature, as well as comment with your suggestions!